# When is __proto__ useful?

Tags: javascript

When is `__proto__` useful?

A lot of browsers support it, but because not all do, programmers seem to be scared of using it. I've never seen it in any code (such as the libraries jQuery and backbone.js).

When is `__proto__` useful? Is it just a geeky thing for completeness?

Comment: It's useful for confusing interview questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__proto__` is deprecated and should not be used.  Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto - <strike>But Opera supports `__proto__` and *not* `Object.getPrototypeOf`, so beware.</strike>

That said, `Object.getPrototypeOf` is, like the name says, used to get the prototype of an object.  I've never found this useful yet.

**Edit 2012-02-06** Opera supports `Object.getPrototypeOf` as of `11.60`.

Comment: Opera supports `Object.getPrototypeOf` as of 11.60.

Comment: __proto__ not supported IE<11;

Answer (score 2):

It is useful if you are going to modify an objects prototype and need to find out if it has been already modified.

Note that `__proto__` is deprecated, instead you should is `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

[MDN Documentation on **proto**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto)